# Unable to resolve dependency HttpClient in net.core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to use IHttpClientFactory. I've read the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0
Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddSingleton<INasaStream, NasaStream>();
            services.AddSingleton<INasaProvider, NasaProvider>();
        }
// another methods remove for clearance
```

NasaStream.cs

```
public class NasaStream : INasaStream
    {
 // some variables declaration
        public NasaStream(IOptions<AppSettings> options, HttpClient _client, ILogger<NasaProvider> _logger)
        {
            settings = options.Value;
            client = _client;
            logger = _logger;
        }
}
```

There is no error with compilation. But when I try to run my app, there is an error:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Mars.INasaStream Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Mars.NasaStream': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'Mars.NasaStream'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Mars.INasaProvider Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> Mars.NasaProvider': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'Mars.NasaStream'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Mars.SolDataQuery Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Mars.SolDataQuery': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'Mars.NasaStream'.)

Why do I do wrong?

Comment: What if you take in IHttpClientFactory instead?

Comment: You can use  typed client `services.AddHttpClient<INasaStream, NasaStream>();` and remove the `services.AddSingleton<INasaStream, NasaStream>();` Since provider is singleton, the transient client will then become captive dependency.

Comment: @Nkosi I've tryed. I use vs code 1.53 and after run command "dotnet run" nothing happened. I wait for about 5 minutes (instead of 20-30 sec) but I didn't see no errors, no result. It looked like the system hung.

Comment: @Magnus I've tryed. But the same situation like I've described upper : I use vs code 1.53 and after run command "dotnet run" nothing happened. I wait for about 5 minutes (instead of 20-30 sec) but I didn't see no errors, no result. It looked like the system hung.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's was my mistake. I couldn't see errors and debug log because I switched them off. It didn't mean that my code not work.
Correct answer was done by @Nkosi

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddHttpClient<INasaStream, NasaStream>();
        ...
    }
```

I should use typed client, that's all